# How to get sed to substitute for all but one character

Tags: sed

I have a statement of the form `atPhysAddress[1][1.10.0.0.98]` i would like to remove all details except for the first one in the second bracket, or whichever value falls there, how can i achieve this?(i.e i would like to only leave out the first integer in the second bracket)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example with

```
$ echo "atPhysAddress[1][1.10.0.0.98]" | sed 's/\(\[.*\]\)\[\(.\).*\]/\1[\2]/'
atPhysAddress[1][1]
```

To only get the first number in the second bracket:

```
$ echo "atPhysAddress[1][12.10.0.0.98]" | sed 's/.*\]\[\([^.]*\).*\]/\1/'
12
```

Comment: is it possible to have only the second 1

Comment: @sosytee: if you mean that you only want the single char in the second pair of brackets, you can have it with `echo "atPhysAddress[1][1.10.0.0.98]" | sed 's/.*\]\[\(.\).*\]/\1/'`

Comment: @enzotib: while you're at it, can you please also show how this first "value" can be captured even when it consists of several digits before the first dot?

Comment: @sosytee: see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
sed -r 's/\[([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\]/[XX.\2.XX.XX.XX]/'
```

which matches `[` followed by a sequence of 5 dot-separated integers followed by `]` and then resubstitutes the 2nd (with XX marking the removed ones - optional of course). The use of the `-r` option makes the expression easier to read but you could re-write it in POSIX sed if GNU sed is not available. By changing \2 to \1, \3, \4 etc. you can choose which number to re-substitute.

```
echo "atPhysAddress[1][1.10.0.0.98]" | sed -r 's/\[([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\]/[XX.\2.XX.XX.XX]/'
atPhysAddress[1][XX.10.XX.XX.XX]
```